# Writing UnitTests for a Service Fabric Application Class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, azure-service-fabric

I am writing unit tests for a Service Fabric Application class. I am running into some errors which I don't understand how to fix.
The class definition is of the sort:

```cs
namespace SearchService
{
    internal sealed class SearchServiceClass : StatelessService
    {
        //variables defined followed by constructor
        private string jsonStr;
        public SearchServiceClass(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            //constructor stuff
        }
        
        public bool IsDataJsonLoaded
        {
            get
            {
                return !(jsonStr == null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The application has a test class defined as follows:

```cs
namespace SearchService.Tests
{
    //[TestClass]
    public class SearchServiceClassTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SearchServiceClassConstructor()
        {
           var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass();
           Assert.True(searchServiceClass.IsDataJsonLoaded);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
> parameter 'context' of
> 'SearchServiceClass.SearchServiceClass(StatelessServiceContext)'.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

Edit: I have been looking at ServiceFabric.Mocks. What I understand is that I need to use the `MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default` to create a mock context. How do I do this, is the following the right way?:

```
var searchServiceClass = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
```

Comment: Constructor of `SearchServiceClass` take one parameter so you need to pass it when creating the object of it. Since, you can't not create the object of `StatelessServiceContext` so you should be use the mock while invoking the constructor.

Comment: If you wan't the default behaviour this is the right way. Otherwise you can create a new `MockStatefulServiceContextFactory` using `MockStatefulServiceContextFactory.Create()` with all the required parameters. Using the default is ok based on the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [ServiceFabric.Mocks](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks) library, to create a test instance of your service by using the following code:

```cs
var serviceInstance = new SearchServiceClass(MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Default);
```

As an alternative to the `Default` context, you can also build a customized instance:

```cs
var newUri = new Uri("fabric:/MockApp/OtherMockStatelessService");
var serviceTypeName = "OtherMockServiceType";
var partitionId = Guid.NewGuid();
var replicaId = long.MaxValue;
var context = new MockCodePackageActivationContext("fabric:/MyApp", "MyAppType", "Code", "Ver", "Context", "Log", "Temp", "Work", "Man", "ManVer");
var context = MockStatelessServiceContextFactory.Create(context, serviceTypeName, newUri, partitionId, replicaId);
var serviceInstance = new SearchServiceClass(context);
```

See [this sample test](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/c8f3e5a594fbd262acf394ee1a9ceae866f46633/test/ServiceFabric.Mocks.Tests/ServiceTests/ActorCallerServiceTests.cs#L26) and [this one](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/5dd32df54861421eb1db03c9b80abafe95093d2e/test/ServiceFabric.Mocks.Tests/MocksTests/MockStatelessServiceContextFactoryTests.cs#L30) for more information.